# How to force project to work only within it's directory?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am writing a solution with two projects, say, 'Core' and 'App'. App is only used to test Core. Core uses some data in it's directory. But the problem is, when I call Core methods that use those files, CLR searches for them in Solution\App\Debug\bin instead of Solution\Core\Debug\bin. That means that I have to copy files to App folder. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: you need to compile both Core an App to a common folder (instead of bin\debug) so that the required files get copied. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165411.aspx

Comment: You would have to copy the files anyway, wherever your library is used. To avoid this, you should add them as resources of the library

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your core project is being referenced by your app project. By default an executable has, as his current path, the folder where it is started (In this case, Solution\App\Debug\bin).
Since it looks like your Core project needs another application to run, it most likely is some kind of class library, that usually has no external files.

One option would be to set a config value to the position of the files, so Core would know where to look (remember, if your Core project is a class library and gets imported as a dll, its config file needs to be called [DLL name].dll.config to work).

A second option would be to add this files to Project Resources (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).